# C# database save add line break to datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm facing a problem where `ExecuteScalar` is sending a few `datetime` parameters to the database and I get an error

> Invalid cast nvarchar to datetime

SQL Server Profiler shows that the `datetime` has a line break in the middle of the date like this:

```
@inspection_start='2015-09-10 /n
00:00:00',
```

I've checked all the data types are correct.

Does anyone know what can cause this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe share some code ...?

Comment: OK the datatypes are correct.   You have a line break in an nvarchar.   That will not cast to datetime.

Comment: The data types aren't correct. You have datetime data but for some odd reason, you're passing it across as a string (`nvarchar`), thus opening yourself up to opportunities for problems such as the one you describe. If you were passing this data *as* `datetime` data, the issue couldn't arise.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OP stated sending a few datetime parameters to the database.

Comment: @Frisbee - yes, but they're obviously **not** sending datetime parameters because there's no possible way that they contain newlines. If they *were* sending datetime parameters, *as* datetimes, they'd be going across as a binary blob.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I get something is strange but how is it going across at all?   If the parameter could not be converted the .NET SQL.data.client should throw the error.   There is a bit more to this story we are not getting.

Answer (score 1):

To start, the

> Invalid cast nvarchar to datetime

is telling me that you are sending a `string` instead of a `DateTime`, and if you are declaring your  `@inspection_start` as a `DateTime` in SQL then this should work for you:

```
// oldInspection_start is the var you already have (inspection_start) 
// with the line break (\n)
string oldInspection_start = "2015-09-10 /n 00:00:00"; 
string newInspection_start = oldInspection_start.Replace("/n", string.Empty);
yourCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inspection_start", Convert.ToDateTime(newInspection_start));
```

Your code should be similar, so just change it as you want to

Answer (score 0):

If its datatype is string then try to remove/replace '\n' character. Can you paste the code how you are passing parameters and calling ExeculteScalar method.

Answer (score -1):

my declaration of the variable

```
public DateTime? InspectionStart
```

this is how i call the procedure

```
int newid = 0;
            try
            {
                Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
                newid = (int)db.ExecuteScalar(
                    StoredProcedures.SaveInspectionPortNewReport,
                    inspection.InspectionStart)
             }
```

and this is how i receive it in the sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[inspection_port_new_reports_save](
 @inspection_start datetime
)
```

the type is definitely date time. debugger shows the date time as its supposed to be. just a simple datetime

Comment: Follow the debugger into the executeScalar-method and beyond, somewhere the parameter is converted to a string.